# IDisposable Control added to Form inside using statement?

Tags: c#, winforms, idisposable, using

In the code example below, does the RadioButton rb still exist in Form mainForm after the code leaves the using statement and rb is disposed?

```
using (var rb = new RadioButton())
{
    rb.Text = "Test Radio Button";
    rb.Checked = true;

    mainForm.MyPanel.Controls.Add(rb);   
}
```

Comment: No, you disposed it.

Comment: Why not just build the code and see what happens?

Comment: @LarsTech Strictly speaking, the object still exists, but it has been disposed, so it's trash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still exists as an object, but it *may* be trash, as you have `Dispose`d it, once execution leaves that `using` block.